# Equivalance form for Slerp in quaternions interpolation

Tags: interpolation, quaternions

In all the books I have found that Slerp have two forms:

**A**

[image]

**B**

[image]

I know that all the forms from **A** are equivalent but I don't know why the forms from **A** are equivalent with the form from **B**.

Can you explain me why?

Thanks!

http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/234325/Winter2014-2015/ho/WCFiles/10_Animations_bw.pdf pag 38

Comment: What do you mean by Slerp?

Comment: Spherical linear interpolation - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take the first version of (A), call it 
$$ Slerp_1(p,q,t) = p (p^* q)^t$$
while
$$ Slerp_B(p,q,t) = \dfrac{p \sin((1-t)\omega) + q \sin(t\omega )}{\sin(\omega)}$$
where $\omega$ is the angle between $p$ and $q$ (and to have this make sense, we need $0 < \omega < \pi$).

Note that if $u$ is any unit quaternion, $(up)^* (uq) = p^* u^* u q = p^* q$, so
$$Slerp_1(up,uq,t) = u\; Slerp_1(p,q,t)$$
But it's also clear that $$Slerp_B(up,uq,t) = u Slerp_B(p,q,t)$$
(with the same $\omega$, i.e. the angle between $up$ and $uq$ is the angle between $p$ and $q$).

In particular, taking $u = p^*$ we have 
$$Slerp_1(1,p^*q,t) = p^*\; Slerp_1(p,q,t)$$
and so to prove $Slerp_1(p,q,t) = Slerp_B(p,q,t)$ it's sufficient to consider the case $p=1$.  In this case, we have $Slerp_1(1,q,t) = q^t$.

Now we can write $q = \cos(\omega) + \sin(\omega) v = e^{\omega v}$ (the polar form of $q$) where $\cos(\omega)$ is the scalar part of $q$, which is the angle between $1$ and $q$,  and $v$ is a purely imaginary unit quaternion.
Again we'll need to assume $0 < \omega < \pi$ (there is no unique definition of $(-1)^t$ as a quaternion).  Then 
$$q^t = e^{\omega t v} = \cos(\omega t) + \sin(\omega t) v$$  On the other hand,
$$Slerp_B(1,q,t) = \dfrac{\sin((1-t)\omega)+ (\cos(\omega)+\sin(\omega) v) \sin(t\omega )}{\sin(\omega)}$$
and expanding out the first sine makes this $\cos(\omega t) + \sin(\omega t) v$ as well.